# problemas al intentar abrir un ejecutable jar de un proyecto de apache netbeans 12.0

Tags: netbeans, apache, jar

Intente crear un archivo .bat para correr el ejecutable jar, actualizé java, el Openjdk y nada. Debo añadir que si me abren los proyectos creados en la versión 8.2

Comment: ¿Qué significa *nada*? ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Qué contiene tu archivo `.bat`? Es difícil ayudarte sin información.

Comment: intenta realizar un limpiado de proyecto y reconstruye nuevamente